# Table structure for tags

Tags: postgresql, database-design

Say I want to store some image ids and their tags in a Postgres 9.3 DB, so that I can:

1) Given an image id, I can get its tags;

2) Given a tag, I can find those images which have this tag.

Which table structure is better for this problem?

a) `image_id` as PKEY, column `tag` stores the tags associated with this image as an array;

b) `tag` as PKEY, column `image_id` stores the image_ids who have this tag as an array;

c) `(image_id, tag)` as PKEY.

d) Other table structure.

I think c) is better, but I don't have any real experience, so any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: c is the default solution that works in almost any situation where a relational database is used.

Comment: What else do you want to do with the database? If it is just image ids and tags it sounds like overkill and there will be better solutions without a database. Are these image ids and tags of multiple persons? Are they shared? Will the images be stored in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your option C is better primarily because it can be indexed by tag and also enforce a foreign key back to the image table.

Solution b can also be indexed by tag, but cannot have a good foreign key constraint and you'll have to run an expensive query when deleting images.

Solution a has the foreign key, but cannot be indexed by tag and will be the slowest of the solutions, depending on the specific query.